# Uncaught ReferenceError: WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions is not defined

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

I had a .Net 1.1 Webapplication which I have converted to the .Net 3.5 and published on the Windows Server 2012. There is a grid in a page where I need to delete a records with the cross button in the grid. But when I try to delete it shows the following error in the Chrome Console

> GET
>   http://10.72.10.225/Models/SEIIAG/WebResource.axd?d=3IplHgLpPO4L8SEYBdyuKR9…fWWwa68LbCK6T7EgwTmR_WdnTJJbBQZJoJJGdKMX0cZCVl9eahgU1&t=635161970660000000
>   500 (Internal Server Error)
>
> ```
> Uncaught ReferenceError: WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions is not defined
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Workaround 1:
In case the page where the problem is observed is based on .master page Sitefinity template.
Add the GetPostBackEventReference manually to the .master page in the OnPreRender event handler. In order to do that you will need to add a code-behind to the master page.

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
   base.OnPreRender(e);
   var control = this.Controls[0];
   this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(control, string.Empty);
}
```

Workaround 2:
In case the page or page template uses asp:LinkButton controls change them to asp:Button controls.

Taken from [Here](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/Missing-WebForm-DoPostBackWithOptions-function)

Answer (score -1):

Got the solution

1. Go to IIS
2. Select your Virtual Directory
3. Select Handler Mappings
4. Double Click on that
5. Select *.axd and click Edit button
6. Change the value of executable section to

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll

7. Click Ok